# How to get line numbers in my python 2.7 script mode?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I been using Dev-C++ and I am quite use to it's user interface and line numbers, because its easy for me to debug my code and error has I'm a beginner in programming field I do a lot of error in programs but can debug using line no on its left side. 
I start python 2.7 recently and am having trouble look for error because it has no line numbers in script mode and I have to count line from top if the error is in 29 or 40 line.
I have seen YouTube video tutorials were they have line numbers in their python script mode, I have been looking for them but couldn't find them.
So if anyone can guide or help me with this, so I can do my programming in python easily.
Attaching pictures so that to be clear what I'm asking for:
;[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGyt0.png)

Comment: Are you using Dev-C++ to edit your Python code? Have you considered an alternat editor, such as Atom.io?

Comment: The Vim editor has the option of showing line numbers. You can also just jump directly to it with, say, `53g`. 

You can also use the python debugger, pdb, from a shell.

Comment: No, sir I'm not using Dec-C++ to edit my python codes.I'm just familiar with these to yet, Dev-C++ and python, don't know about others yet.

Comment: You can download idleX which can help you with line numbers in your python raw editor. Have a look and download this plugin: http://idlex.sourceforge.net/extensions.html

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you're using the `IDLE` editor which comes with Python.

From taking a quick look at it, I didn't see how to display line numbers. But what you can do is to look at the bottom line of the window which shows the current line of the cursor.

Another option would be to use another editor to write your python programs. There's a wide variety of choices. You can google for "python editor" and find good comparisons. Popular editors include *Atom*, *Visual Studio Code*, *PyCharm*, ...